# Build error using vercel Failed fetch and ENOTFOUND NEXTJS 13 beta

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy my site to Vercel however I keep getting the following error messages. Everything works as intended in my local environment. I know the issue is coming from the two fetch files linked below because, if I comment them both out I can deploy it. As far as I understood, there shouldn't be a need for the Vercel Url, but If I don't have it in I get a different error saying failed to parse. I can build the app on my local system but only when I have the dev server running. I have done this many times using NextJs12 but now I'm using the new beta 13 version I can not find a solution.

[image: Error when using vercel build]

Function causing the error along with another that is almost identical

```
   const allVenues = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/venues/getAllVenues`)
      const listings = response.json()
      return listings
    }
    
    export default async function Home() {
      const venues = await allVenues()
      
      return (
       <main>
          <section className='p-5'>
            <Venues venues={venues} />
          </section>
          <h1></h1>
          
       </main>
      )
    }
```

Api endpoint

```
import prisma from '../../../prisma/client'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
) {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
    
        try{
            const result = await prisma.venue.findMany()
            res.status(200).json(result)

    } catch(err){
            res.status(403).json({err: 'error fetching venues'})
    }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Try to deploy your api endpoints first without the app directory and if they are deployed you can then deploy your project with the app directory

Comment: It may be a silly question but how would I deploy the app directory afterwards, wouldn't I get the same error? I am using vercel build, is there a better method?

Comment: No, you wouldn't get the same error because you can't access your api endpoints during build time to fetch data, so a workaround is to deploy the api endpoints first, because then the new deploy where you fetch the data in your app directory can access your old builded url at build time and the data is there. So you do two deploys, the first one you just comment out all your fetch requests in the app directory and after the first deploy you can add them back.
Keep in mind that this way your newest build always accesses the endpoints of your previous build

Comment: I decided to try an alternative method with the last project. However on the next project I am creating, I am getting the same errors as above. I have added the api endpoints first and tried to upload the files with the fetch functions. I will edit the question to represent the current status